# Better way to not have transaction fail if there is no left value to update? (Nested Set PHP/SQL - PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, nested-sets

**tldr (short version):** Is there a more efficient way to have my update left values query not fail and ruin a transaction if there are no left values to update?

---

**Long Winded Version if need more info. Otherwise skip to code below:**
So I'm using PDO, and I'm creating a categories class to handle my nested set, hierarchical categories table. I'm preparing my statements to then execute in a transaction (below), BUT the transaction keeps failing if I try to add children to certain nodes because there is no left value to update. This is the solution I came up with, however i'm wondering if there is a much better way to do it. A way to maybe not mark the transaction as failed if no left value is found that greater than the compare node.

---

the left value checks if the remaining of the values from compare node (where I want to insert) to the end of the tested set (right value of the $base_node) are all right values. If they are that means there is no left value to update (which would cause transaction to fail) and it instead makes SQL2 a stand in select query instead of an update query). Else, if there are lft values to update, it updates those.

---

$compare_node = the object representation of where we want to place the new category under (or after or before).

$base_node = The base, very top node of the hierarchy (the node with a left value of 1).

$SQL2 (the if else statement portion) is the main part  i'm wondering about, but being new to programming i'm open to ANY suggestions or criticisms of my code :)

```
////////////////UNDER
    if ($post_values['new_cat_location'] == "under" && $nRows > 1){

        //setup prepared statements for lef and right updates
        $sql1 = "UPDATE ".static::$table_name." SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > :compare_lft";
        $update_right = $database->connection->prepare($sql1);
        $update_right->bindParam(':compare_lft', $compare_node[0]->lft);

        if($this->remaining_all_right($compare_node[0]->rgt, $base_node[0]->rgt) && $compare_node[0]->lft + 1 == $compare_node[0]->rgt){
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM ".static::$table_name." WHERE id=:id";
            $update_left = $database->connection->prepare($sql2);
            $update_left->bindParam(':id', static::$cat_root );
        }else{
            $sql2 = "UPDATE ".static::$table_name." SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > :compare_lft";
            $update_left = $database->connection->prepare($sql2);
            $update_left->bindParam(':compare_lft', $compare_node[0]->lft);
        }

        //setup prepared statement for insert of new category
        $sql3 = "INSERT INTO ".static::$table_name." (cat_names,  cat_descriptions, lft, rgt) VALUES (:cat_names, :cat_descriptions, :compare_lft +1, :compare_lft +2)";
        $insert_new_cat = $database->connection->prepare($sql3);
        $insert_new_cat->bindParam(':cat_names', $post_values['cat_names']);
        $insert_new_cat->bindParam(':cat_descriptions', $post_values['cat_descriptions']);
        $insert_new_cat->bindParam(':compare_lft', $compare_node[0]->lft);
        }
```

And then here is my transaction code in case its needed.

```
//###################################################################################################//
//################## TRANSACTIONS BEGIN HERE BASED ON THE STATEMTNTS PREPED ABOVE     ###############//
//###################################################################################################//
        $database->connection->beginTransaction();
        $database->connection->exec('LOCK TABLE '.static::$table_name.' WRITE');

        $confirm_compare_node  = self::find_by_id($post_values['node_to_compare']);

        if($compare_node[0]->lft != $confirm_compare_node[0]->lft || $compare_node[0]->rgt != $confirm_compare_node[0]->rgt){
            $error = "The category tree has changed since you started. Please try again";
            echo $error;
        }else{
        $update_right->execute();
            unset($sql1);
            if(!$update_right->rowCount()){
                $database->connection->rollBack();
                $error = "Transaction failed: could not update right values";
                echo $error;
            }else{
                $update_left->execute();
                    unset($sql2);
                    if(!$update_left->rowCount()){
                        $database->connection->rollBack();
                        $error = "Transaction failed: could not update left values";
                        echo $error;
                }else{
                    $insert_new_cat->execute();
                    unset($sql3);
                    if(!$insert_new_cat->rowCount()){
                        $database->connection->rollBack();
                        $error = "Could not insert the new Category";
                        echo $error;
                    }else{
                        $database->connection->commit();
                        $database->connection->exec('UNLOCK TABLE');
                        //rebuild the levels of the categories
                        self::rebuild_cat_levels();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What should it do if there's no row to update?

Comment: `rowCount == 0` is not an error, why do you treat it as one?

Comment: If there is no row to update, BUT doesn't fail for some other reason, I want it to not cancel the transaction. But I want to distinguish this from instances where there is a row to update, but something goes wrong and files to do so. 

rowCount == 0 is a separate query that is above that for when I have no populated the table with anything yet. I added it here because it would overwrite my row==0 code that I have above. (basically the code for insert below, before, and after all were working when there were at least 2 items in the table, but not before, so I made separate ones for building)

Comment: The only reason the transaction is being cancelled is because you call `rollback()` whenever `rowCount() == 0`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. I was thinking you mean $nRows. yes, the tutorial I found used rowCount as the method for checking that the query was successful. Would you recommend another way? I'm not sure how else to check that the execute functioned properly.

Comment: If you want to tell if the query got an error, check the value of `execute()`. It will be `true` when successful, `false` when there's an error.

Comment: Oh, well darn, yeah that much better. I wonder why the tutorial had me do it this way :/. So basically just 

(if(!$insert_new_cat->execute();) ?

fantastic. thank you so much, and sorry for the confusion, I'm very new to programming and also this site. I really appreciate your time. Is there any karma system or way I can reward you for your help? Thank you again.

Comment: It might be application-specific. For instance, if you're doing a transfer between bank accounts, you subtract from account 1 and add to account 2; if account 1 doesn't exist, you abort the transaction.

Comment: Don't worry about my karma. :)